# Display YouTube videos in a grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have displayed images in a grid view. But I don't understand how to display YouTube video in a grid-view?

Comment: Do you have youtube videos id or video url?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a template column with literal control in it.
2. on itemdatabound fill the literal with the embed code of the YouTube video

Example:

```
((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litvideo")).Text = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/r6BHyv6nkAs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="Row" HeaderText="YouTube Video">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblYTVideoURL" runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("YTVideoUrl")  %>></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ControlStyle CssClass="Row"></ControlStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then from the code behind:

```
protected void grvYoutubeVideo_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[1];

        if (lbl.Text != "")
        {
                //string YTVideoURL = lbl.Text;    //"http://www.youtube.com/v/AyPzM5WK8ys";

                //string OBJYTVideo = "<object width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
                //OBJYTVideo += "<param name=\"movie\" value=\"" + YTVideoURL + "\"></param>";
                //OBJYTVideo += "<param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param>";
                //OBJYTVideo += "<embed src=\"" + YTVideoURL + "\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"";
                //OBJYTVideo += "allowscriptaccess=\"always\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></embed></object>";

                //lbl.Text = OBJYTVideo;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this, you can put all this in .html and open. After you will easy add this to asp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <object width="425" height="355">
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/sSe_RmPlOLM" />            
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sSe_RmPlOLM" type="application/x-    shockwave-flash"
                wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355" />
        </object>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Video">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                  <iframe id="video" width="420" height="250" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src='<%# "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Eval("VideoURL").ToString().Split(new string[] { "v=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1] %>' frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                                  </iframe>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```